# jqplot - chart not showing up x-axis properly

Tags: charts, jqplot

I have following code to generate chart using jqPLot, I'm not able to figure out why it is not showing x-axis properly

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            $data = [['2012-03-03',1,'03 Mar 12'],['2012-03-06',4,'06 Mar 12'],['2012-03-07',1,'07 Mar 12'],['2012-03-08',1,'08 Mar 12'],['2012-03-15',2,'15 Mar 12'],['2012-03-18',1,'18 Mar 12'],['2012-03-21',3,'21 Mar 12'],];
            jQuery.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
            jQuery.jsDate.config.defaultCentury = 2000;
            jQuery.jqplot("chartdiv",[$data],
            {
                series:[{renderer:jQuery.jqplot.BarRenderer}],
                seriesDefaults: {
                    showMarker:true,
                    pointLabels: { show:true },
                    rendererOptions: { barMargin:35}
                },
                axes :{
                    xaxis :{
                        renderer :jQuery.DateAxisRenderer,
                        min : '2012-03-01'
                    }
                }
            }
        );
        });
```

Comment: Why use category renderer with date?

Comment: I was experimenting with other options, code corrected now.

Comment: Could you please expand on what do you exactly mean it is "not showing the axis correctly" and/or give us a http://jsfiddle.net presenting your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it. After giving it a run, I have noticed that after the first date you had a `NaN`, was that what you meant "not showing the axis correctly"?

So the problem was here that you were missing `jqplot.` between `jQuery` and `DateAxisRenderer` in `renderer :jQuery.DateAxisRenderer`.

[Now it looks fine, as shows this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/hC88c/)

Comment: I just removed it. It was a left over from my other example on jsfiddle, which I simply forked :) I updated the example and it is now removed from the eexample. BTW was this your problem, did it help you?